# Get event-object before event is handled

Tags: javascript, arguments, dom-events, parameter-passing

Is there a way to get the `event`-object or rather any passed argument outside its handler?

Look at this example, as you can see I try to get the handled mouse button. This however will fail since `event` is `undefined`.

```
var foo = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};

var bar = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};

document.onclick = event.which === 1 ? foo : bar;
```

The point is not that this situation doesn't work or that I don't know how to get it to work. Rather that I don't understand how the arguments are passed if a function is attached this way.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: just wondering, is there a reason why you can't create a handler that checks `event.which` then call either foo() or bar() and passing in the event object?

Comment: @AlexCheuk Of course I can, however I was wondering why the approach above doesn't work. It's not the fact that this situation doesn't work. Rather that I don't understand how the arguments are passed if a function is attached this way.

Comment: It just wont work, because I believe document.onmousedown is suppose to be a function and it expects a function when you define a custom handler. The event object is then passed in as an argument when the event is handled.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about [how events work](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). Event objects are created in response to an event and are destroyed once the event is complete subject to normal garbage collection rules. You seem to be expecting a `window.event` object to be always present, but there isn't one in most browsers. Only the IE event model has a window.event object, the W3C model passes an event object to called listeners as an argument.